# Multi-threading using python in robot framework, involving nested function calls

Tags: python, multithreading, robotframework

I have the following python code "ex.py" that is trying to execute two parallel threads of exact same functionality :

```
import thread

class PrtArg(object):

    def print_name1(tname,*args):
        cnt = 0
        print "Inside print_name1"
        while cnt < 10:
            cnt += 1
            print "%s : %s\n" % (tname, cnt)

    def print_name(tname,*args):
        cnt = 0
        print "Inside print_name"
        while cnt < 10:
            cnt += 1
            print "%s : %s\n" % (tname, cnt)

    def m_prt(self,*args):
        thread.start_new_thread(print_name, (args[0],))
        thread.start_new_thread(print_name1, (args[1],))
```

And I have a test suite "example.robot" that has the following :

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation    MultiThread Program
Library  ex.PrtArg

*** Test Cases ***
Test title
    [Documentation]  MultiThread
    [Tags]    DEBUG
    m_prt  a  b

*** Keywords
```

When I execute this, I get the following error:

```
==============================================================================
Ex :: MultiThread Program
==============================================================================
Test title :: MultiThread                                             | FAIL |
NameError: global name 'print_name' is not defined
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ex :: MultiThread Program                                            | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
```

Now, I came across [this](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#communication-when-using-threads) which says "threads should generally communicate with the framework only from the main thread". Isn't that what the above code does? I'm not even returning a value. Just printing to console. As expected, when I modify my "example.robot" to the following, it works fine:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation    MultiThread Program
Library  example4.PrtArg

*** Test Cases ***
Test title
    [Documentation]  MultiThread
    [Tags]    DEBUG
    print_name  a
    print_name1  b

*** Keywords ***
```

So, my questions are :

1. How do I get to run a testcase with static keywords which call other functions in the python library? Is this possible?
2. Is multi-threading this way supported by robot framework?
3. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try declaring your method in static because they are in an instance of a class and the `start_new_thread` doesn't take that.

So you code would look like that

```
import thread

class PrtArg(object):
    @staticmethod
    def print_name1(tname,*args):
        cnt = 0
        print "Inside print_name1"
        while cnt < 10:
            cnt += 1
            print "%s : %s\n" % (tname, cnt)

    @staticmethod
    def print_name(tname,*args):
        cnt = 0
        print "Inside print_name"
        while cnt < 10:
            cnt += 1
            print "%s : %s\n" % (tname, cnt)

    def m_prt(self,*args):
        thread.start_new_thread(PrtArg.print_name, (args[0],))
        thread.start_new_thread(PrtArg.print_name1, (args[1],))
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. It worked! So, not an issue with threading or nested function calls afterall. The thing that got me confused is that as a standalone script, the same worked fine.